# How to automate scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I've got a little problem with my scrapy spider. So I set up scrapy and all is working fine but everytime I want to scrape a website I have to start the spider by myself. But I want it to be full automated and doesn´t know how to do.

Actually I start the spider with *cmdline.execute*. I thought I could simply write a *while True* loop but turns out it doesn´t work. And i found out, that the spider doesn´t really quit. Hard to explain. Pycharm says "Finished with exit code 0" but if i put a *print("End of program")* after the *cmdline.execute* it doesnt print out anything.

And at this point I'm confused what to do. Can you help me?

Comment: Call your spider using a subprocess and create a cronjob for it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you all but I´ve found a solution. I wrote a BASH script and in that script I am able to loop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I noticed that you are new. What was the script? What resources did you use to find the solution? What version of python? What OS? The point of stackoverflow is to document solutions. If everyone abandoned their thread once they solved the issue the website would be pointless. Members take time out of THEIR day to help. They are not paid anything. The least we can do as members of this site is share a link or a code snippet so others might be helped in the future. Always document your work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Scrapyd is an application for deploying and running Scrapy spiders. It enables you to deploy (upload) your projects and control their spiders using a JSON API.

Some tutorials:

[How to deploy scrapy spider using scrapyd?](https://medium.com/@jebaseelanravi96/scrapy-tutorial-part-5-ab1e04553f82)

[Deploy, Schedule & Run Your Scrapy Spiders](https://scrapeops.io/python-scrapy-playbook/extensions/scrapy-scrapyd-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for scheduling spiders.

**CRON**:
Like Alexander commented you can create a CRON Job, it think this is best suited for a situation where you have just a few spiders that you're not gonna change the schedule for often.

**[Scrapydweb](https://github.com/my8100/scrapydweb)**: It's a web interface for managing scrapyd. You must host it yourself. Quite easy to use in my experience.

**[Zyte](https://www.zyte.com/)**: Practially the same as scrapydweb but it's a SaaS app that you do not host yourself. Very easy to use but expensive.

**[Gerapy](https://github.com/Gerapy/Gerapy)**: I have not tried it but I believe it's similar to scrapydweb but seems to be built on some more modern frameworks.